# Run boost asio io_service forever

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I call `boost::asio::io_service::run()` and it returns immediately since it has no jobs to do.
A different thread will queue work later on, but I don't want the `run` thread to exit.
On solution is to busy wait on run:

```
while(true) service.run();
```

But that would waste CPU when there is no work to do.
Another way is to wait on an event that is raised every time something is queued to the service.
This way has a race: If one thread stops doing work and then a second thread posts work and raises the event before the first has a chance to wait on it, the first would wait forever.
I would rather avoid that and have the service know when there is work to do.
Is it possible to do something like:

```
while(true)
{
    service.wait_for_work();
    service.run();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `io_service::work` object exists for this purpose.

Comment: I don't understand fully. Is your solution just `io_service service; io_service::work work(service); service.run();`?

Comment: Yes, and if you need to control the lifetime of the work object, store it in a smart pointer. The work object will prevent io_service::run from exiting while it exists.